# Bootstrap 3 responsive without jumping

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have question about this template

```
<body style="" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
      </p>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/span-->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>© Company 2013</p>
  </footer>

</div><!--/.container-->



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="offcanvas.js"></script>
```

Window size: 1252 x 983
Viewport size: 1242 x 574

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ this is example 
And this is bootply : http://bootply.com/108089

I want to do feature when you minimise width of page to get responsive without page jumping , is this possible to make it more smooth ? 
Thanks for your help , regards.

Comment: You want to look at CSS transitions

Comment: is this possible to do with jquery ?

Comment: It's better to use transitions as it's hardware accelerated, but yes

Comment: Can you tell me please how tu but this navbar from example on left side of page ?

Answer (score 1):

http://davidwalsh.name/animate-media-queries

This is a great article that covers more than you need including changing div colours and more.

As is this one

http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/

What you want to do is (in my opinion) uneccessary for everyone other than other developers! Not many users are going to resize their browser when viewing your site but hopefully these will help. However as a developer I would go 'oohhh' 'ahhhh' when I saw it in effect.

Comment: Really? I always just assume they have used `transition: all` on that element's attributes and qualify it as lazy.